# What is most efficient way schedule work using WorkManager for a system level event- using addContentUriTrigger in Constraints or BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver, background-process, android-workmanager

I am having a use case where I need to register an incoming call in through my app and later use that data for something. One thing that is clear to me is that we need a `WorkManager` to run in the background to perform this task, however, the confusion lies in the implementation of this. The logical approach is that the `WorkManager`'s `doWork()` should be triggered when the call event occurs.

Now, there can be two different implementations for this-

1. Using a `BroadcastReceiver` (to register the call event) and then enqueue the `workRequest` in the `onReceive()` of the `BroadcastReceiver`
2. Adding the Constraints in the `workRequest` in the following way:

```
//some code here
                
               val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                        .addContentUriTrigger(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true)
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build()

                val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<JobWorker>().apply {
                    setConstraints(constraints)
                    setInitialDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                }.build()

                WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
                    .enqueueUniqueWork(
                        "CALL_TRACKER",
                        ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                        workRequest

//some code here
```

Will this implementation of using the `addContentUriTrigger` trigger start the WorkManager immediately just as the BroadcastReceiver will do or will it add some delay and start the WorkManager when the resources are available to the android system resources?

Moreover, is using the BroadcastReceiver the best solution to this, please let me know if a better solution exists. Can the Android team remove the permission to read Call information in future due to which this method might not work?

I need the details of all incoming calls for later processing.

Thanks for the help!

Links I have gone through:
[addContentUriTrigger](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints.Builder#addContentUriTrigger(android.net.Uri,kotlin.Boolean))
addTriggerContentUri

Answer (score 0):

> Will this implementation of using the addContentUriTrigger trigger
> start the WorkManager immediately just as the BroadcastReceiver will
> do or will it add some delay and start the WorkManager when the
> resources are available to the android system resources?

Most likely yes.
Looks like expedited requests might provide a way for you to prioritize the requests: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started/define-work#expedited, but even so, there's no guarantee about always fulfilling it. So you have to take into account that depending on resource availability some tasks might get deferred.

> Moreover, is using the BroadcastReceiver the best solution to this,
> please let me know if a better solution exists.

That depends how critical to you is the response speed to a phone call. I see in your sample you are setting a delay of 30 seconds, so maybe triggering the workmanager instantly it's not crucial?

> Can the Android team remove the permission to read Call information in
> future due to which this method might not work?

Yes, they can.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The response speed to a phone call doesn't matter as long as it is guaranteed that the WorkManager is triggered and starts the work. So does using the trigger ensure that the work manager will begin its work and not miss logging the call without getting triggered by the BroadcastReceiver explicitly?